# Is there a way to have node preserve command line history between sessions?

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop

When I run `node` from the command line with no arguments, I enter an interactive shell. If I execute some commands, exit node, and restart node, the up arrow doesn't do anything (I'd like it scroll through my previous commands).

Is there a way I can invoke node interactively such that it will remember my old commands?

Comment: So what have you tried so far? [node-shell](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-shell) seems to have the features, among many others.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could use [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/rlwrap.html) to store node.js REPL commands in a history file.

First, install rlwrap (done easily with a package manager like apt-get or brew etc).

Then add an alias for node:

```
alias node='env NODE_NO_READLINE=1 rlwrap node'
```

I'm on OSX so I add that alias to my `~/.bash_profile` file, and would reload my bash_profile file via `source ~/.bash_profile`.. and I'm good to go!

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was using the (incorrect) command: `rlwrap node` and was frustrated as to why the Node REPL wasn't preserving my history. This solved my problem!

Comment: Though rlwrap make you loose the pretty node repl colors.

Comment: Also the tab completion

Comment: FYI, dreampulse's answer preserves colors and tab completion. :)

Answer (score 17):

I found a nice little project, which solves the problem:

> https://www.npmjs.org/package/repl.history

install using npm (`npm install -g repl.history`)
and run `repl.history` on the command line.

Comment: This method preserves repl colors and tab completion. Yay!

Comment: @SamH Edits should not change or extend the original answer in any way. They are meant only to clarify grammar, spelling, formatting, etc. This is due in part to the fact that edits are approved by the community, not the owner of the post you're editing. If you have suggestions, they belong in comments or your own answer. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts

Answer (score 8):

io.js 2.0 includes support for [persistent REPL history](https://iojs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl).

```
env NODE_REPL_HISTORY_FILE=$HOME/.node_history iojs
```

The maximum length of the history can be set with `NODE_REPL_HISTORY_SIZE`, which defaults to 1000.

In io.js 3.0+, REPL history is enabled by default and `NODE_REPL_HISTORY_FILE` is deprecated in favor of `NODE_REPL_HISTORY` (default: `~/.node_repl_history`).

Comment: I made an alias for this like @badsyntax: `alias iojs='env NODE_REPL_HISTORY_FILE=$HOME/.node_history iojs'`

Answer (score 8):

As well check file .node_repl_history in user home directory.

Answer (score 7):

Node supports this natively.

When in node REPL just issue the following command to save the history:

```
$> .save ./file/to/save.js
```

[Reference: Commands and Special Keys](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_commands_and_special_keys)

Answer (score 5):

I like the combination of both dreampulse's and badsyntax's answers. With repl.history, plus an addition to my .bash_profile I get the behavior I expect, which is command history and syntax highlighting in the node interactive shell, but bypassing repl when called with arguments (to run a script).

```
npm install -g repl.history
```

Then edit your ~/.bash_profile, adding:

```
function node(){
    if test "$#" -lt 1; then repl.history
    else env node $@; fi; }
```

Now restart your shell or run `. ~/.bash_profile` and you're good to go.

---

Now running

```
$ node
```

will open the repl.history nodejs interactive shell, and

```
$ node program.js [...]
```

will run program.js with node as expected.