# Using rlwrap with Node.js REPL, how could node '.break' (Ctrl-C) not be interpreted as a SIGINT by rlwrap?

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop, sigint, rlwrap

Following this discussion on how to [preserve command line history between sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18511787/is-there-a-way-to-have-node-preserve-command-line-history-between-sessions), I defined the following alias:

```
alias node='env NODE_NO_READLINE=1 rlwrap node'
```

It works perfectly for the history persistance but now, everytime I do a Ctrl-C to send node's '.break' command, rlwrap takes it too but as a SIGINT: it cleans everything and suicides (as described in [its man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/rlwrap.1.html)), thus forcing me to restart a node session (having to recall my var, funcs, requires etc), while I just wanted to '.break'...

Any way to get back the classic node behaviour?

- Ctrl-C : breaks
- Ctrl-C again (or on a blank line): exit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Avoiding SIGINT

`node` changes the meaning of  <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> by unsetting its [interrupt character `VINTR`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signal-Characters.html) (usually <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd>) to avoid the interrupt signal that it would otherwise get.

After starting up, `rlwrap` is sleeping all the time, until something happens on your terminal or on the pseudo-terminal (`pty`) used by e.g. `node`. This "something" can be a keypress by you, or output from `node`.

Every time this happens, `rlwrap` will copy `nodes`s terminal settings (including `VINTR`) ) to its own tty.

However, if `node` *only* changes its terminal settings, this, by itself,  won't wake up `rlwrap`, which will thus keep the old settings on its own tty. Transparency will then be broken: When you press <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> `rlwrap` will still interpret it as a `SIGINT`, while `node` would have understood a `.break` command.

There ia a special, very obscure,  `pty` mode ([EXTPROC](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-readline/2011-01/msg00004.html)) that allows the pty master (`rlwrap`) to be woken up by a slave's changes in terminal settings, but this is very un-portable. This is why, since version 0.41, `rlwrap` has the much less elegant `--polling` option that makes it wake up every 40 milliseconds and copy the slave's terminal settings.

#### Forward <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd>

Starting with version 0.43, `rlwrap` can directly forward special keys even when in readline mode by binding
such a key to `rlwrap-direct-keypress` in `~/.inputrc`:

```
$if node
   "\C-c": rlwrap-direct-keypress
$endif
```

However, `node` *only* gives <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> special treatment when it itself uses readline (try `NODE_NO_READLINE=1 node` and then type  <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd>) to see what I mean)

In such cases (i.e. when a command does its own line editing), one has to force  `rlwrap` into readline mode:

```bash
$ rlwrap --always-readline node
```

This  has the unfortunate and unavoidable  drawback that whanever a command asks for single
keypresses (`Continue? Y/N`) one has to type an
extra <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

And then there *still* is the problem sketched above: if the terminal's interrupt character is not changed, `node` will never see the <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> (but get a `SIGINT` instead)

There are two solutions. Either:

```
stty intr undef # disable interrupt character
rlwrap --always-readline node
stty intr '^c'  # re-enable CTRL-C
```

or:

```
 rlwrap --polling --always-readline node # --polling means: continually wake up and wacth  node's interrupt character
```

#### Wrapping up

To make a long story short:

- Add `"\C-c": rlwrap-direct-keypress` to your `inputc`
- Temporarily unset the terminal's interrupt character, or use `rlwrap --polling --always-readline` as above
- Try to live with the extra Enter for single keypresses

Comment: I tried to use `rlwrap-direct-keypress` without success.

Comment: `rlwrap` has a few new options that might help - I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: With this configuration, pressing ctrl-c prints ^C to the screen and it takes an Enter to update the screen. But that's better than nothing. I'm now wondering how to get this with node REPL scripts, not just the node REPL itself, as in your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43677273/371334 I.e. `rlwrap --polling --always-readline -z node_complete ./myrepl.js` still has ctrl-c broken.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. Did you `reset` the terminal? Could you build  `rlwrap` with the `--enable-debug` configure option, run `rlwrap --debug --polling --always-readline node`, press CTRL-C a few times, and mail me the resulting `/tmp/rlwrap.debug` file? (you find my address on my [Github page](https://github.com/hanslub42)