# Can the Babel CLI be made to remember command history?

Tags: node.js, shell, babeljs, rlwrap

With the Node CLI, I can add this to my shell statup file:

```
alias node='env NODE_NO_READLINE=1 rlwrap -S "> " node'
```

When I now run `node`, I can press the 'up' arrow key and the previous command from the previous session is put on the command prompt. As per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18513951/165716). See also [iojs' history support](https://iojs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl).

I want to have this functionality with the [Babel CLI](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/), but changing the alias from `node` to `babel-node` does not change its behaviour.

[EDIT]: I've added this as [an issue to Babel](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1965) on Github.

Comment: Did you try to add a `rlwrap` option `-a` like this: `alias babel='env NODE_NO_READLINE=1 rlwrap -a -S "> " babel'`. (`man rlwrap` for an explanation)

Comment: I get `rlwrap: warning: on this system, the getopt() library function doesn't
grok optional arguments, so '-S' is taken as an argument to the -a option
Is this what you meant? If not, please provide an argument` (osx)

Comment: When I supply a blank string as the `-a` argument, there's no warning, but history doesn't work. I've got it figured now; I'll add an answer.

Comment: Scratch that. I didn't figure it out.