# save nodejs history from interactive command-line session

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop

After using `node` in interactive/command line mode to explore, how can I copy my command history to a text file for my own future records?

**The up arrow key recalls previous `node` statements, and furthermore already persists across logins, so the history is already being saved somewhere in node.js**. 
But where is it saved? How can I copy it?

But I could find nothing in `node --help`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to have node preserve command line history between sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18511787/is-there-a-way-to-have-node-preserve-command-line-history-between-sessions)

Comment: @Shaunak Indeed the `.save` answer is there, but this is not the same question.  The other question is about fixing history when it is broken and not saving, or when something is up with the C library that supports readline/history on the machine where node is installed, or some similar thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The read-evaluate-print-loop or [REPL](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) has a documented [list of special nodejs REPL commands](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_commands_and_special_keys), including a save command:

```
 .save /path/to/save/my/history
```

Also, look in `~/.node_repl_history`

Comment: Saved me! I didn't save my work when using a temporary file and I was able to piece it all back together using this `~/.node_repl_history` file. I had to reverse the lines to have it make sense, but it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

you just need to run this command

```
node app.js > log.txt
```

this command will save all command prompt output to a file